# Am I misusing (this) stackexchange

Tags: discussion

I'm not really asking questions that I can't find the answer for. Instead, I'm asking questions to clarify what I am asking, testing the water to see if they're coherent, and also perhaps doing the same with answers.

Is that a misuse of the site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That seems to describe how I use the site.

I try to keep my questions as specific as possible. Usually I think I know the answers already, but I am not sure. I am hoping in asking the question that others will point me in the right direction, confirm that the direction I am heading in is reasonable or offer something unexpected. Over time as I understand these questions better, I hope to write an answer to my questions if I can add something more by doing so to the answers already there.

It is similar for my answers. Since I am not sure the answers are correct, I try to ground the answers on a reference. Even if it is a logical proof, I ground the answer on a textbook quote, proof checker or some sort of generator to confirm the answer both to myself and to any reader who happens to come along.